# Multiple regression, simple regression or other?

Tags: linear, variable

I'm attempting to put together a research proposal where area knowledge (Western Asia) is my speciality but where the statistical methodology I need to answer my research question is not and I'm confused by the options available.

So, to my research question: can variation in social movement participation during the 2011 Syrian Uprising be attributed to variation in role-choice behaviour?

'Role-Choice behaviour' is defined in the Identity Theory literature as '*opting to fulfil the role expectations associated with one identity rather than another*' and is measured as '*time spent in that role*'.  I expect to measure social movement participation as '*time spent protesting on the streets*'.

Now I would like to examine the role-choice behaviour associated with six identities: familial, professional, ethnic, national, class, and sectarian and see which of them is associated with increased/decreased levels of participation.

Whilst I know social movement participation is the dependent variable, my question, then, is the following:  do I have one independent variable with 'role-choice behaviour'divided into six sub-variables (familial, professional, ethnic, national, class, sectarian) requiring linear regression, or do I have six independent variables with 'familial role-choice behaviour', 'professional role-choice behaviour', 'ethnic role-choice behaviour', 'national role-choice behaviour', 'class role-choice behaviour', 'sectarian role-choice behaviour' requiring multiple regression?

Any help appreciated massively,

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you need a range of dummy (0/1) variables, k-1 per category, where k is the number of possible outcomes of each variable. For example, if family status has 2 levels, then you need one dummy, taking value 1 if married, 0 otherwise. However, if you have 3 levels, e.g. married with kids/married no kids/single, then you need two dummies. The same applies to the rest of the variables. That way, you will be able to measure the effect of each category on your dependent variable in comparison with the outcome that is out (e.g. if married with no kids and married with kids dummies are both positive that means that being single reduces the dependent variable vs being maried). However, you need to be careful with the number of variables you use, depending on your sample size and on how predictable your dependent variable is. If your sample size is small and the d.v. fairly random, then you will over-fit your sample and the coefficients will capture noise.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: To add, to my mind I don't have 'outcomes' as you state.  Choice-role behaviour is measured simply as 'time spent in role'.  So, an hypothesis, for example, may be 'the more time spent fulfilling familial role expectations, the more time spent protesting'.  I just don't know whether under the 'role-choice behaviour' rubric I have six independent variables (family, profession, ethnic, national, class, sectarian) or just one independent variables (role-choice behaviour with six sub-variables - family, profession, ethnic, national, class, sectarian).

Comment: If you printed a table with a small sample of your dataset it would help

Comment: This is for a research proposal, so I don't have the data for the dataset yet.

Comment: As @JohnnieThick said, a sample table would make a big difference -- you could share fictional data matching the format your real data will take.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make multiple regression for your model to be able to capture the correlation between these features, but there is a technical part in order to make a good prediction you can use multiple regression with weight decay(l1,l2) to not overfit the model if this feature is very large, there is another cheap alternative you can use LASSO(Least Absolute Selection and Shrinkage Operator) if you find these features with zero weight then use another that doesn't have zero weight. I hope you understand my point of view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I will read up on your suggestions and get back to you if necessary.  Best regards.

Comment: Just a quick question though.  Can 'role-choice behaviour' not be thought of as my independent variable and 'family', 'profession', 'ethnicity', 'nationality', 'class' and 'sect' as the attributes or sub-variables of said variable?  Much like 'gender' can be considered a variable and 'male' and 'female' as its attributes or sub-variables...

Comment: I don't understand the nature of your data, But I don't think that will be good as I said it will be more helpful to make it independent variables if it isn't obvious to make it together (sub-variable)

Comment: Please don't put contact info in your posts. If you want, you can list it on your userpage.